# Tags dictionary and dictionaries merge

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two tags, [dictionary](/questions/tagged/dictionary) and [dictionaries](/questions/tagged/dictionaries), where *dictionaries* should be a synonym for *dictionary*. I added *dictionaries* as a synonym to *dictionary* but haven't gotten enough upvotes for it. I saw people requesting here so I thought this would be the right place to get this done.

Comment: Makes sense to me - it's got my upvote and I've posted it in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have been completed. [dictionaries](/questions/tagged/dictionaries) now remaps to [dictionary](/questions/tagged/dictionary). Well spotted.

Comment: Cool I guess I wait for a mod to tag it status-completed